# How to allow Guest session to access printers and scanners?

Tags: 12.04, printing, scanner, guest-session

I want to allow the Guest session to access printers and scanners. I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What printer do you use? I have an Hp psc 750 and I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by unplugging and plugging again of the printer from the USB port when you are in guest session mode. Thus, Ubuntu will know that the curent user is the owner of the device.

Also, this post can be useful: [Mount device with r/w access to specific user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30268/mount-device-with-r-w-access-to-specific-user).